# Jenkins: connect to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, amazon-rds

so I'm trying to get data from database on AWS using psql client on docker. Unfortunately, I'm getting `PAM authentication failed...`. My step looks that:

```
def readPostgres() {
    docker.image("{ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/psql-client:latest").inside("--entrypoint=''") {
      sh "PGPASSWORD=jenkins psql -h {URL}.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U jenkins -d database -c 'SELECT * FROM timestamps'"
    }
}
```

Which leads to:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "URL.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (IP_ADDRESS), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "jenkins"
connection to server at "URL.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (IP_ADDRESS), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "(HOST)", user "jenkins", database "artifacts", no encryption
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to deal with this error, can somebody give my any tips?

Comment: PostgreSQL thinks it is supposed to be using IAM authentication, rather than simple password authentication.